# What is NODE_PROVIDER of vyper listener and client

Tags: python, vyper

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvrHherxiu4&list=PLFPZ8ai7J-iQMTChqif-XVP8DYABA4rx1&index=9&ab_channel=MoralisWeb3)

The problem is I don't know what is `NODE_PROVIDER`

I had tried watching Марат Гудков answer,

```
3 weeks ago
here is the video from this Moralis channel about ".env" file 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hOzyhrfAKA, and setting up web3
```

But I don't found any line mention value of it.

**Question:**
What is `NODE_PROVIDER` in the Vyper listener and clients?

Answer (score 0):

It is `'http://127.0.0.1:7545'`

```
web3_connection = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545'))
```